# R: Speical case of mathematical annotation

Tags: r, plot, graphic

I want to set a title with mathematical symbol. In detail I want to write, that k is an element of [1;12]. I dont know how to do it.

My approach is the following one:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(k %in% w))
```

But I can't reach to remove the w by [1;12].

Maybe someone can help me

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want the title to be. Perhaps you could make a graphic of exactly what you want and post it? My best guess is that you want `expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]")))`. If this is a good guess let me know and I (or someone) can make an answer out of it.

Comment: That was already the answer. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hard code the title like this:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]")))
```

Or say you want the `1` and `12` to come from values in a variable. You can use `bquote` as in these examples that I made up:

```
w <- c(1, 12)
plot(1:10, main = bquote(k %in% group("[", list(.(w[1]), .(w[2])), "]")))

z <- 1:12
plot(1:10, main = bquote(k %in% group("[", .(min(z)) * ";" * .(max(z)), "]")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the right solution. Do you know how can I place it into arrangeGrob ? I need it to define a titel of a column with grid.arrange. So grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(bar1, top = "k = 0"), arrangeGrob(bar2, top= expression(k %in% group("[", "1;12", "]"))) didn't work there

Comment: Sorry - I'm the last person to ask about very fine details of grid objects. Perhaps ask another question.